# Have one button with two different behaviors for click and mouse down

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I wish to have the same button behave different for **left** click and **left** mouse down.
On click it should add 15 to the current number, on mouse down it adds 1 for as long as the mouse is down

```
var value = 0;
document.getElementById("Addbtn").addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown);
document.getElementById("Addbtn").addEventListener("click", mouseClick);

function mouseDown() {
  this.value++;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.value.tosSring();
}


function mouseClick() {
  this.value += 15;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.value.tosSring();
}
```

**The problem** both events gets fired and I wish to distinguish them so when mouse is hold down click won't fire and vise versa.

Is there a way to achieve this?
Cheers

Comment: mouseup doesnt solve the issue here? instead of click I mean

Comment: @Shai nope - mouse up also gets fired when releasing the mouse in mouse down - so it will do +1 and at the end will add another 15 :(

Comment: Ahh ok got it, so you want to avoid mouseDown on click, are you ok with waiting 1 or 2 seconds before starting the mouse down event?
I mean if you can do a timeout of 2 seconds for example on mouse down, then if click happened, cancel the timeout.
This will cause the mouseDown to happen but do nothing unless user holds the mouse for more than 2 seconds

Comment: To restate @Shai 's question-- how long does the user have to be holding the mouse button down for you to consider it a "hold" and not a "click"?

Comment: @shai can wait a second max before starting to add 1 in `mouse down` but no longer than that. Is this the right approach? if so **can you share  a piece of code that does that**

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comment, since `click` and `mousedown` are related and there is no way to disconnect them from each other, the solution can come with a bit of a trick, adding a timeout to determine if it was a "long hold" of the mouse down.
Added a little bonus to disable the click if mouse down has been triggered, you can remove it if not needed.
Also notice, its on a 1 second waiting (1000 ms), change it according to how much you can wait before saying its a mousedown event. 1 second seems long to a user sometime ( about 500 ms is a sweet spot for me)

```
        var value = 0;
        var mouseHoldTimeout;
        var mouseDownDone = false;
        document.getElementById("Addbtn").addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown);
        document.getElementById("Addbtn").addEventListener("click", mouseClick);

        function mouseDown() {
          mouseHoldTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            value++;
            mouseDownDone = true;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = value.toString();
          }, 1000);
        }


        function mouseClick() {
          if (mouseHoldTimeout) {
            clearTimeout(mouseHoldTimeout);
            mouseHoldTimeout = null;
          }
          if (mouseDownDone) {
            mouseDownDone = false;
            return;
          }
          value += 15;
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = value.toString();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

**mousedown** event will trigger when you click either the **left or right** or even the **middle**.It does not matter which one do you click it runs the function. In contrast **click** event will trigger when you click the **left**.So it seems when you click the left you trigger mousedown(for left) and click event.
As the document provides the click event triggers after mousedown and mouseup.

[js mouse basics](https://javascript.info/mouse-events-basics)